# Using FragmentInteractionListener for transferring object fragment-to-fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, runtime-error, android-fragmentactivity

I am using onFragmentInteraction as a function for communication between fragments. The two fragments are confirm_screen and detailsForm. I intend to send object of class Person(declared in MainActivity.java file) from detailsForm to confirm_screen. The function onFragmentInteraction is part of the interface OnFragmentInteractionListener. The interface is implemented(function implemented) in MainActivity.java file. The function body is:

```
     @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Person person)
    {

        Confirm_Screen personinfoFrag = (Confirm_Screen)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.confirm_Screen);

    //    Log.d("name", "Taimoor");

       if (personinfoFrag!=null) {
            // If confirm frag is available, we're in two-pane layout...

            // Call a method in the confirm to update its content
            personinfoFrag.SetPerson(person);

            Log.d("name", "Taimoor");



        }
       else
       {
           FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
           transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, personinfoFrag);
           transaction.addToBackStack(null);

           Log.d("name", "I am in else you dummies");
           personinfoFrag.SetPerson(person);
           transaction.commit();
       }
    }
```

Here is the function onCreateView of DetailsForm class(DetailsFrom.java) where onFragmentInteraction is called:

```
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details_form, container, false);


        P= new Person();


        //Button Setting
        submitButton=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.setperson);

        //Setting Values
        Name=((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputName)).getText().toString();
        hairColor=((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputHairColor)).getText().toString();
        CNIC=((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputCNIC)).getText().toString();
        skinColor=((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputSkinColor)).getText().toString();
        description=((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.pDescription)).getText().toString();
        suspectedCrime=((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputPersonCrime)).getText().toString();
        lastKnownLocation=((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.inputLocation)).getText().toString();
        //viewholderColor=
       // imagename=
        P.setCNIC(CNIC);
        P.setDescription(description);
        P.setHairColor(hairColor);
        P.setImagename(Name);
        P.setLastKnownLocation(lastKnownLocation);
        P.setSuspectedCrime(suspectedCrime);
        P.setSkinColor(skinColor);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {

                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onFragmentInteraction(P);

                    Log.d("msg", "I am here");
                }

                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_detailsForm_to_confirm_Screen);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

Here is the onAttach function in DetailsForm class(DetailsForm.java):

        @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }


Here is where we set the person object newPerson in confirm_screen class(Confirm_Screen.java). The object newPerson is set with the person object passed in OnFragmentInteraction in DetailsForm class.


      //Setting Value of P
    public void SetPerson(Person person)
    {
        newPerson=person;

        Log.d("name", newPerson.getName());
    }
```

Here is where we set the attributes of person object to textviews which will be displayed on our screen.
We set the values in onCreateView function of Confirm_Screen class:

```
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_confirm__screen, container, false);

        ConfirmBtn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.confirmPerson);
        //Setting Values
/*
  public TextView pname;
    public TextView cnic;
    public TextView pDescription;
    public TextView pskinc;
    public TextView shairc;
    public TextView pcrime;
    public TextView Location;
 */

        pname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pname);
        pname.setText(newPerson.getName());
        shairc=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.shairc);
        shairc.setText(newPerson.getHairColor());
        cnic=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.CNIC);
        cnic.setText(newPerson.getCNIC());
        pskinc=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pskinc);
        pskinc.setText(newPerson.getSkinColor());
        pDescription=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pDescription);
        pDescription.setText(newPerson.getDescription());
        pcrime=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pcrime);
        pcrime.setText(newPerson.getSuspectedCrime());
        Location=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.Location);
        Location.setText(newPerson.getLastKnownLocation());
    .....rest of the code
}
```

Our issue is when we run the app on device and reach the detailsForm. When we click the submit button on DetailsForm message displays:EAGLEVISION HAS STOPPED WORKING.

The error on logcat console is:
attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.textview.settext(java.lang.charsequence)' on a null object reference
The setText function it is pointing to is on line in OnCreateView of confirm_screen.

The person class for reference is:

```
   class Person
   {

       private String ID;
       private String name;
       private String hairColor;
       private String CNIC;
       private String skinColor;
       private String description;
       private String suspectedCrime;
       private String lastKnownLocation;
       private int viewholderColor;
       private String idimageref;
       private String imagename;
   }
```

Getter/Setters have been written for each attribute.

Kindly if anyone could help??